# Save and print generated barcode as image

Tags: flutter, barcode

I am using the [barcode_widget](https://pub.dev/packages/barcode_widget) to generate both barcode and 2d QR code. But I also need to print and save the codes.

My Current code for generating bar code and qr code is as below:

```
    Center(
      child: BarcodeWidget(
        data: widget.product.productId!,
        barcode: Barcode.code128(),
        width: 200,
        height: 200,
        drawText: false,
      ),
    ),
```

and

```
    BarcodeWidget(
      data: widget.product.productId!,
      barcode: Barcode.qrCode(),
    ),
```

Both are inside a Column and I have two buttons called save and print. So how can I save and print the generated codes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `RepaintBoundary`
Follow these steps:

***1. Create a key.***

```
  GlobalKey _screenShotKey = GlobalKey();
```

***2. Wrap the barcode in a repaint boundary and attach the key***

```
RepaintBoundary(
 key: _screenShotKey,
 child: Center(
      child: BarcodeWidget(
        data: widget.product.productId!,
        barcode: Barcode.code128(),
        width: 200,
        height: 200,
        drawText: false,
      ),
    )
)
```

***3. Import `dart:ui` as `ui`***

```
import 'dart:ui' as ui;
```

***4. Create a method to take a screenshot of the widget and save it.***

```
  Future<File> takeScreenshot() async {
    RenderRepaintBoundary boundary =
        _screenShotKey.currentContext.findRenderObject();
    ui.Image image = await boundary.toImage();
    ByteData byteData = await image.toByteData(format: ui.ImageByteFormat.png);
    Uint8List pngBytes = byteData.buffer.asUint8List();
    final tempPath = (await getTemporaryDirectory()).path;
    final path = tempPath + "qr.png";
    File imgFile = File(path);
    return imgFile.writeAsBytes(pngBytes);
  }
```

***5. To save in gallery/photos app; Use [GallerySaver package](https://pub.dev/packages/gallery_saver)***

```
 void save() async {
    takeScreenshot().then((value) async {
      bool saved = await GallerySaver.saveImage(value.path);
      print(saved);
    }).catchError((onError) {});
  }
```

Comment: `Image` is from a dart library called `dart:ui` but to avoid overshadowing names (since `Image` is already in `Material`)...I imported `dart:ui` as `ui` - I'll add the import in an update.

Comment: Okay, I tried your code but it didn't work

Comment: What error did you get?

Comment: No error. I got nothing. Checked the files and there is no image saved. Here is the link https://pastebin.com/RLEbY09h

Comment: Uhmm, do you want the image to be saved in the phone's gallery?

Comment: yes because the user might need to check it later?

Comment: I've added a `save` method..Call that instead.

Comment: does the gallery saver plugin requires any special treatment? like upgrading the minSdk version? beacuse I just got `Execution failed for task ':gallery_saver:compileDebugKotlin'.
`

Comment: Try these:         minSdkVersion 21
        compileSdkVersion 31

Comment: I already have minSdk 23 and compileSdkVersion 31. Still got some error. turns out the issue was with an older kotlin version. Upgraded that and it works fine now. Thank you so much